How can I exclude a keyword from the list?
I have come up with this list of categories and keywords by which the products should be categorised. You may check it below:
const categories = {
    "Meso": ["snicla", "šnicla", "krmenadla", "pileca prsa", "belo meso", "pileća prsa", "krilca"],
    "Čokolada": ["čokolada", "cokolada"],
    "Majonez": ["majonez"],
    "Kečap": ["kečap", "kecap"],
    "Senf": ["senf"],
    "Paradajz": ["paradajz"],
    "Kobasice": ["kobasica"],
    "Posebne kobasice / Salame": ["posebna kobasica", "pileca posebna", "salama"],
    "Pileća prsa": ["pileća prsa", "pileca prsa"],
    "Pašteta": ["pašteta", "pasteta"],
    "Ćevapi": ["ćevapi", "cevapi", "ćevapčići"],
    "Šnicla": ["šnicla"],
    "Krilca": ["krilca"],
    "Voće": ["banana", "banane", "jabuka", "jabuke", "mandarine"],
    "Sokovi": ["borovnica", "borovnice", "jabuka", "jabuke", "narandža", "pomorandže", "breskva", "breskve"],
    "Kuhinjski aparati": ["Ketler za vodu", "Seckalica MC 400"],
    "Za domaćice": ["daska za peglanje", "bokal", "čistač", "cistac",],
    "Vileda": ["vileda"],
    "Filtriranje vode": ["Akvafor", "Akvaphor"],
    "Alati": ["metla", "auto set"],
    "Maziva": ["majonez", "kečap", "kecap", "senf", "sos"]
};

Now, what I need is to exclude certain keywords from some categories. For example, I have a category "Voće" (eng. fruit) and inside of that category I want to have a "banana" keyword included, but I don't want to have "choco banana" or "krem banana" included in that category (since it isn't a fruit but a candy). The solution I've tried you may find below:
// Function to filter products based on exclusion rules
function filterProducts(category, exclusions) {
    return categories[category].filter(product => {
        let lowerCaseProduct = product.toLowerCase();
        // Check if product does not include any exclusion keyword
        return !exclusions.some(exclusion => lowerCaseProduct.includes(exclusion));
    });
}

// Example usage: Exclude "Krem banana" from the "Voće" category if found as a keyword
let excludedKeywords = ["krem banana"];
categories["Voće"] = filterProducts("Voće", excludedKeywords);

console.log(categories["Voće"]);

Unfortunately, I couldn't manage to get the desired result with this piece of code.

krem banana isn't in the category, so there's nothing to exclude.

Can't you just use == instead of includes() to it has to match the exclusion exactly?

Seems like you need to split() the exclusion and then add another some() so you check each word separately.
This way banane is removed as expected.


const categories = {"Meso": ["snicla", "šnicla", "krmenadla", "pileca prsa", "belo meso", "pileća prsa", "krilca"], "Čokolada": ["čokolada", "cokolada"], "Majonez": ["majonez"], "Kečap": ["kečap", "kecap"], "Senf": ["senf"], "Paradajz": ["paradajz"], "Kobasice": ["kobasica"], "Posebne kobasice / Salame": ["posebna kobasica", "pileca posebna", "salama"], "Pileća prsa": ["pileća prsa", "pileca prsa"], "Pašteta": ["pašteta", "pasteta"], "Ćevapi": ["ćevapi", "cevapi", "ćevapčići"], "Šnicla": ["šnicla"], "Krilca": ["krilca"], "Voće": ["banana", "banane", "jabuka", "jabuke", "mandarine"], "Sokovi": ["borovnica", "borovnice", "jabuka", "jabuke", "narandža", "pomorandže", "breskva", "breskve"], "Kuhinjski aparati": ["Ketler za vodu", "Seckalica MC 400"], "Za domaćice": ["daska za peglanje", "bokal", "čistač", "cistac",], "Vileda": ["vileda"], "Filtriranje vode": ["Akvafor", "Akvaphor"], "Alati": ["metla", "auto set"], "Maziva": ["majonez", "kečap", "kecap", "senf", "sos"] };

function filterProducts(category, exclusions) {
    return categories[category].filter(product => {
        let lowerCaseProduct = product.toLowerCase();

        // Check if product does not include any exclusion keyword
        return !exclusions.some(exclusion => exclusion.split(' ').some(ex => lowerCaseProduct.includes(ex)));
    });
}

// Example usage: Exclude "Krem banana" from the "Voće" category if found as a keyword
let excludedKeywords = ["krem banana"];

console.log('Before', categories["Voće"]);
categories["Voće"] = filterProducts("Voće", excludedKeywords);
console.log('After', categories["Voće"]);




The question says that banana should be included in the category, but you removed it.
